# Azure functions: Multiple functions with different authentication

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have an Azure Function which authenticates with a B2C Active Directory. Now I want to have another function which does not require authentication and I placed it in the same Functions App. But as Functions are configured per Functions App it requires authentication as well. Can I configure the authentication on a per function basis or do I need to create a separate Functions App for anonymous functions?

Comment: You need to create a separate Functions App for anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create a new function app. Because B2C is aimed at the app level, not the function / trigger level. If you want a function with a different authentication strategy, the way is to put it in a new Azure Function App.