# Azure functions: do separate function apps mean separate containers?

Tags: azure-functions

Our team is thinking of deploying a an azure function app with several functions inside.  One function would be a health status endpoint that we want to keep open as far as authentication is concerned. Anyone should be allowed to check the status of the function application.

In reading, I see that if you want to implement different authentication rules for different functions, we need to create separate function applications.

So in our use case would do something like this:

Resource Group Widgets

- function app A - AD Authentication enabled.

  - function X
  - function Y
- function app B - no authentication enabled

  - health status function.

In the above scenario, is it correct to assume that the health status function and app would be deployed in a separate container?  If that's the case, there would be no point in exposing that endpoint because it would not prove that the web services for function app A are up and running.
I guess we could write logic inside the health status app that so that it checks the status of function app A, but simply returning a "hello world" would be useless.

Can someone with more experience comment on this ?
Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Just to be explicit, ideally, this is what we want:

Resource Group Widgets

- function app A

  - function X- AD Authentication enabled
  - function Y- AD Authentication enabled
  - function health status - No Authentication

And we don't want to use function keys - just Azure AD authentication, if possible.

Comment: *In reading, I see that if you want to different authentication rules for different functions, we need to create separate function applications.* That is incorrect. Function authentication can be specified at the function level. Having a healthcheck function that isn't running alongside the thing that's being healthchecked makes no sense. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#authorization-keys

Comment: @DanielMann ok.  I was reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60859179/azure-functions-multiple-functions-with-different-authentication.

Comment: @DanielMann can you point me to an article or something that shows how to set up AD authentication at the function level and not at the app level?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/94888/how-to-add-an-azure-function-which-does-not-requir.html also seems to indicate you cannot use AD auth at the function level.  it's at the app level.